# What interaction effect glmulti generates in A*B*C*D and A+B+C+D?

Tags: r, model, glmulti

I am using `glmulti` to run hierarchical linear models and select the best model. I have 4 predictors (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) to the DV, and my goal is to run all main effect models plus all combination of interaction effects (i.e., `A:B`, `A:C`, `A:D`). How do the following two models differ from each other?

```
library(glmulti)

# wrapper
glmer.glmulti <- function(formula, data, random = ""){
glmer(paste(deparse(formula), random), data = data, family = binomial)}

# model 1
glmulti(DV ~ A+B+C+D, level = 2, fitfunction = glmer.glmulti, random = "+ (1|ID)", 
method = "g", data = df)

# model 2
glmulti(DV ~ A*B*C*D, level = 2, fitfunction = glmer.glmulti, random = "+ (1|ID)", 
method = "g", data = df)
```

I know that "when an interaction between two factors is included in a model, then adding or not these factors as main effects does not change the model" ([Calcagno, 2010](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v034i12)). Seem that model 1 and model 2 should produce the same results because `A*B*C*D` essentially includes the main effect of each predictor. But the two codes select a different best model.

Thanks!

Comment: @useR Thanks for the comment. Because I set `level = 2`. According to the `glmulti` package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmulti/glmulti.pdf), pairwise interactions are also used if `level = 2` .

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason, but `A*B*C*D` also includes 3-way and 4-way interactions, whereas model 1 would only have pairwise interactions. I think the comment in `?glmulti`:  "(higher order interactions are currently
ignored)" refers to `level > 2`, not that it would ignore higher order interactions when you specify them in the formula.

Comment: @useR. It makes sense... I will manually run the higher order interactions, and see if the results much with the `DV ~ A*B*C*D`. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I will post this as an answer if it actually solved your problem.